# Aligning and wrapping the text vertically in a table with multicolumn environment

Tags: tables, multicolumn, wrap

My code is as follows:

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}|l|l|}
\cline{2-3}
                                                                & \textbf{Hypothesis Testing}   & \textbf{Comparison between}            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Mean Comparison}}} & One Sample t-test             & a sample mean and known reference mean \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & Two Sample t-test             & means of two groups                    \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & Paired t-test                 & means of two groups for paired data    \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                          & ANOVA (F-test)                & means of more than two groups          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Variance Comparison}}              & Variance test                 & variances of at least two groups       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Proportion Comparison}}            & Chi\textsuperscript{2} test & proportions of at least two groups     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

output is as follows:

[image: Ouput table]

But the desired output should be:

[image: Desired output]

I have tried the solutions here:

[Wrap text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790932/how-to-wrap-text-in-latex-tables)   and here   [wrap \multicolum](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F115668%2Fwrapping-text-in-multicolumn&ei=jl4dVbL7Csq_PO_igLgH&usg=AFQjCNHnFZG-VYKYN7No5CEHsWMpBb9_Fg&sig2=fJD9CuXwkYmLiC2Wq1Kb4g&bvm=bv.89744112,d.bGg)

But nothing works so far. Could someone help me out please.

Comment: Use `\multirow{4}{1in}{...`

Comment: It makes the first cell i.e "Mean comparison" wrapped but how can i wrap the cells with "Variance comparison" and "proportion comparison" ???

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a line break inside `\multirow` you have to use a length instead of `*` like

```
\multirow{4}{1in}{\centering\textbf{Mean Comparison}}
```

with a `\centering`. Further, since you are using `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}` for first column, all `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}`s are redundant. Removing them will allow the line break and make contents centered as wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}|l|l|}
\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                       & \textbf{Hypothesis Testing} & \textbf{Comparison between}            \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{1in}{\centering\textbf{Mean Comparison}} & One Sample t-test           & a sample mean and known reference mean \\ \cline{2-3}
                                            & Two Sample t-test           & means of two groups                    \\ \cline{2-3}
                                            & Paired t-test               & means of two groups for paired data    \\ \cline{2-3}
                                            & ANOVA (F-test)              & means of more than two groups          \\ \hline
\textbf{Variance Comparison}                & Variance test               & variances of at least two groups       \\ \hline
\textbf{Proportion Comparison}              & Chi\textsuperscript{2} test & proportions of at least two groups     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, your tabular is wider to fit inside the text width. You make consider using `p` or `m` type column for the last column. I have not added it since the idea is to reproduce the table in the picture.

Comment: Works Works Works !!! Thanks for the suggestions as well. :)

Comment: @RahulBalmuri You are welcome `:-)`